# Exclude a single file from DEFLATE in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching, gzip, compression, deflate

I have set my htaccess file to cache and deflate the majority of the usual file types to increase speed, one file particularly though seems to behave oddly when cached and I want to try to exlude this from any deflate and caching commands in htaccess to see if that is the cause.

Because my site is fairly busy it does not make sense to take off all files and slow every user down while I check this over a couple of days so I was wondering?

Is there a line I can put in my htaccess that specifically excludes a particular file (engine.js for example)

regards

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
    <Files (whatever you have this set to deflate)>
         SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </Files>
    <Files (filename).(extension)>
         SetOutputFilter NONE
    </Files>
```

For example, if you were trying to deflate the PHP files, except for one, your code would look like this:

```
    <Files *.php>
         SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </Files>
    <Files myfile.php>
         SetOutputFilter NONE
    </Files>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try tomorrow